# Is Gaussian Process regression appropriate to model non-smooth/somewhat stochastic functions?

Tags: random-forest, gaussian-process

I wanted to test using GPR in my financial modelling to see if it would do a better job than what I'm currently using (Random Forest), but I read somewhere that it is not appropriate for non-smooth functions and also for ones that are strictly non-negative and between certain values as is the case with stocks and currencies. Others argue that they would always use GPR over RF.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Depending on the kernel used one can impose different roughness/continuity restrictions. The strictly non-negativr most likely refers to the kernel function; not to the values. Notice that for financial modelling we want to *extrapolate* so be careful how you validate your model.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! What exactly do you mean by extrapolation? Not the most popular validation method, but what I normally do with regression is I train my model up to the point say n-15, then make a prediction 15 days ahead. Then import separate data of what actually happened (note that this is something the model hasn't seen. Then plot that against the predictions and compute the mse.

Comment: That is fine. Often GPR is validated "internally" ergo it will be over-fitted to actually extrapolate.